# How can I make kubectl silent?

Tags: bash, kubectl

I'm trying to start port-forwarding in the background while suppressing all output. Here is what I've tried:

```sh
kubectl port-forward pod-name 1234:1234 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Yet when I initiate connections, I still see messages like this:

```
Handling connection for 1234
```

As I understand it, both standard output and error should be directed to /dev/null.

My belief seems to be confirmed by the silence of this script:

```sh
echo "hi" > /dev/null 2>&1 &      # test stdout silence
>&2 echo "hi" > /dev/null 2>&1 &  # test stderr silence
```

(Note: I had to run these in a script rather than a shell, to avoid my shell's default output about subshells.)

I don't know what else I can do to suppress the `kubectl port-forward` output. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you know `Handling connection for 1234` is output by `kubectl port-forward pod-name` ?

Comment: @Philippe I know it comes from kubectl because I’ve seen that output before... but now that I think of it, maybe there’s an old instance of kubectl in that shell that I haven’t managed to kill off. I’ll try again with a new shell.

Comment: Try and see if using curly braces to group the command makes a difference. Like this:   { kubectl port-forward pod-name 1234:1234 } > /dev/null 2>&1 &

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what worked in my case (after command execution output is completely silent):

`kubectl port-forward pod-name 1234:1234 2>&1 >/dev/null &`

which says send `stderr` output to the same place where `stdout` output which is `/dev/null`

Tested for:

*Ubuntu 18.04*

*Kernel 5.4.0-70-generic*

*GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)*

Comment: I haven't had a chance to revisit this, but the solution looks good to me. :-)

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw unfortunately I've noticed drawbacks of it. It has problems with redirecting error output, therefore after some period of time `kubectl` will start print error messages to the terminal. I'm still trying to find a way of how to improve it

Comment: The solution below from @sctx works, the one from gokareless doesn't

Answer (score 7):

From my experience it is possible to make kubectl silent by swapping `2>&1` with `> /dev/null`. Otherwise it won't work.

`kubectl port-forward pod-name 1234:1234 > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: This one works better than the selected answer. The other one makes a syntax error on kubectl not finding a named port "null" or something. This one works perfectly with sh.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. The accepted one does not work for me. This one does